# Warning For UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: objective-c, uitextfielddelegate

I am following a tutorial within the IOS 6 Cookbook Fourth Edition on how to hide the keyboard when a user clicks Done. Unfortunately I am getting a warning that I do not understand b/c I'm a java guy pretending to understand this Objective C stuff. I took a screenshot of exactly what I am looking at so that everyone can see exactly where the warning is. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: As a note: you should include the text of the warning, as well as your header file in questions like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the .h file declare this class to implement the protocol by using

```
@interface IT315ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Comment: Should this have an @end after it?

Comment: after you declared all the properties and methods yes

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't declare `it315ViewController` to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in the .h file

Comment: Your cookbook should have a section on protocols and delegates.  That will explain it